# why in lucid, user.save() is not function?

Tags: node.js, adonis.js, lucid

I get row by `findOrCreate()` method and update verification_code. when i want use `user.save()` i get this error :

> user.save is not a function

my code:

```
    let user = User.findOrCreate({mobile: mobile});

    user.verification_code = await Hash.make(code);

    await user.save(); //error is in here 

    sendSMS(user.mobile);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by replace :

```
let user = User.findOrCreate({mobile: mobile});
```

with :

```
let user = await User.findOrCreate({mobile: mobile});
```